# Regex match for a single character delimiter in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am struggling to have a regex match for separating keys and values.

The requirement is that the delimiter is ':', yet the keys can have multiple "::". The values can have ':', but the keys cannot. So the first ':' should be the delimiter. If there is any space before the values, it should be eliminated.

I have the following regex, but it fails for key:value (no space after ':').

```
if ($_ =~ /^(.+?):\s+(.*)$/)
{
  $data{$1} = $2;
}
```

Valid key values are:

```
key:value
key: value
key: value::subvalue
key::subkey:value
key::subkey:value:subvalue
key::subkey: value:subvalue
key::subkey::subsubkey:value
```

Note that key, subkey, value, subvalue can be replaces by any word. My regex works for all, but the first one.

How can I fix it?

I can have an `elsif` and add another regex, but I wonder if I can have a single regex for the whole thing.

Comment: Can we get a sample set of valid and invalid strings?

Comment: I added some sample key values.

Comment: @Amir: please, can you add invalid examples too?

Comment: Is `key:` valid? Can't you just remove the `\s+` from your regex if spaces aren't necessary?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by invalid. The regex should separate the key part from value part.

Comment: I mean "lines that must not be matched by the pattern".

Comment: Any line that has ':' should match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^((?:[^:]+::)*[^:]+):(?!:)\s*(.*)$/
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37k2v)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
/^((?>[^:]+|::)+):\s*(.*)$/
```